# Ubuntu update errors and warnings

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

After running `sudo apt-get update`, Ubuntu update commands shows errors and warnings. Here are those errors:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

More information is at:  http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23971993/plain/

Comment: The PPA mentioned in the error message cannot be used for 16.04 (xenial). Just remove that software source and the error should disappear. It doesn't prevent the system to get and install updates.

Comment: @CelticWarrior many PPA's are not updated to the latest because the developer has either stopped development, stopped supporting it, or abandoned it. But it doesn't mean that older software specifically developed for an older Ubuntu distribution won't work. If you visit the PPA site and look in the dists directory, you can determine the last release available, update your `Software & Updates` and still have access to the software. In this case, no xenial, but wily was still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software developer doesn't have a xenial PPA, but does have a wily PPA. Edit your ppa definition in `Software & Updates` and change xenial to wily.

Many PPA's are not updated to the latest because the developer has either stopped development, stopped supporting it, or abandoned it. But it doesn't mean that older software specifically developed for an older Ubuntu distribution won't work. If you visit the PPA site and look in the **dists** directory, you can determine the last release available, update your `Software & Updates` and still have access to the software. In this case, no xenial, but wily was still there.

update: never use a PPA repository that is for a newer version of Ubuntu than what you're currently running.